# Regex with YahooPipes: Append Text to the end of Description field

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I want to append some text to the end of the description field. How do I select all contents and append to the end of the item field?

Currently the way I do it is a little crude.
Since the description field is an HTML page I am assuming that most often there will exist `</p>`. Hence I replace `</p>` with `</p> Additional text`. The only problem is this occurs anywhere in the body of the HTML page.

Hence here is the way I currently do it with a REGEX box (Sorry I cannot paste an image of my Yahoo pipe):

```
item.description replace </p> with </p> Article Courtesy: ${link}

item.content:encoded replace </p> with </p> Article Courtesy: ${link}
```

This works great with 2 problems.
It does not always occur at end of page, but somewhere in the middle or maybe even at the top.
If the `</p>` does not exist in the HTML page then the content to be added will not go in.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is just to add the text at the end, why not use this

item.description replace $ with Article Courtesy: ${link}

This will just add your string at the end of current content

Comment: I did exactly that.. but now it does not show Article Courtesy anywhere in the post. (Waht was done was REGEX - item.description - replace $ with Article Courtesy: ${link} --- did not work)

Comment: I take that back.. you are right.. The $ works. My problem was I was cutting stuff off the bottom in an arbitrary manner, so when I put the article courtesy at the end it was random.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `</body>` instead?

Comment: There is no </body> in the description or content:encoded field

Comment: In that case it's not really an HTML page.